# Send different email templates based on a condition resque::mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, resque

Hi I have a RoR 4 app where I am using resque-mailer to send async emails. A new requirement requires to send 4 different template based on some condition. I know that I need to have 4 different  views for the templates, but do I need to have 4 different methods in the class that includes Resque::Mailer as well or somehow I can use one method to render different email templates?